# how to calculate shoutPower for my libGdx game?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

this.maxHp = 100;

this.hp = this.maxHp;

it's mean objeact got 100hp and  if we hit object,  it's  subtracted 5 hp from object.

here is method th check if object take damage:

```
 public boolean takeDamage(int dmg) {

    hp -= dmg;

    reddish += 1.0f;

    if (hp <= 0) {

        return true;
  }
    return false;
}
```

here is method to check if bullet hit object:

```
public void checkCollisions() {
    List<Bullet> b = bulletEmitter.getActiveList();
    for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < players.size(); j++) {
            if (b.get(i).isArmed() && players.get(j).getHitArea().contains(b.get(i).getPosition())) {
                b.get(i).deactivate();
                 players.get(j).takeDamage(5);
                map.clearGround(b.get(i).getPosition().x, b.get(i).getPosition().y, 8);
                continue;
            }
        }
```

I need to show taking damage (int dmg), damage might be any variable which we put in  method  takeDamage(int dmg). int this case int dmg = 5;

I can't calculate it this:

result = maxHp - hp

increase result on 5hp with evry hit

5.. 10.. 15.. 20..

here is method, which i put font in:

```
        damageFont.draw(batch, "" + (maxHp - hp), position.x, position.y + 130, 85, 1, false);

    }
}
```

(maxHp - hp) - increase result on 5hp with evry hit  5.. 10.. 15.. 20..

instead this, i need to calculate ammount of deal damage, but not with constant values.

(maxHp - hp) something instead this just should return 5, if we put 5 in    takeDamage(int dmg) 
or 10, if we put 10.

it's amount of damage take with evry hit:

should be 5, 5, 5, 5

not: 5... 10... 15... 20

Comment: What does "result is increased with each step on 5.0" mean? You want something to happen with every five points of damage?

Comment: I think I understand your problem now. Why are you trying to calculate anything? You already know what the damage per hit is -- it's the same `damage` value you're passing into `takeDamage`. It would be better if you explained what you were trying to do instead of trying to explain code. Your character has a shoutPower meter that fills as he takes damage? No matter how much damage he takes, you want shoutPower to increase whenever his health goes down in increments of 5? Forget the code. Just explain what you want to happen in the game.

Comment: I might add other type of weapons, of course I could use constant value, but it's not very easy, for each single weapon, set constant ammount of damage, at the same time damage might change from shout power, or from weapon that I choice in game mode, because of this it's much better to calculate it (not with constant values).
but I don't understand how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like MarsAtomic mentioned you allready have your damage per hit, just save it as a new instance variable and display it instead of (maxHp - hp):

```
private int damageTaken;

public boolean takeDamage(int dmg) {
   damageTaken = dmg;
   hp -= dmg;

   reddish += 1.0f;

   if (hp <= 0) {

       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

and when you draw your font:

```
damageFont.draw(batch, "" + damageTaken, position.x, position.y + 130, 85, 1, false);
```